# Volume control KDE widget - how to load?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, plasma, volume-control

After a recent KDE update in Kubuntu 19.10 I lost the ability to control volume using my laptop keyboard specific volume buttons. It turns out that for the volume control via keyboard to be restored I'd need to launch the KDE Audio Volume widget. Yet, I didn't find this widget in KDE widgets.

So how does one reload this widget by hand?

Comment: have you tried the system settings for keyboard shortcuts?: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/shortcuts.html

Comment: I've noticed that the volume widget "malfunctions" sometimes. Have you logged out and back or rebooted after the update?

Comment: And, don't you see the widget by just typing "vol" in the search bar in the Add Widgets pane?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, I have, that didn't help. Yes, I've tried the search also.

Comment: @Nmath This menu (https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/kde-global.png) has no such shortcuts.

Comment: the pic you linked is from 2018 so I am assuming this is not your screenshot, but in the screenshot you posted, there is a category on the left side "Audio Volume", which should allow you to set your keyboard shortcuts for volume controls.  This is also the case for KDE Plasma 5.12.9 (and most likely above).  See: https://imgur.com/a/j3TXkDS

Comment: @Nmath There is no such thing as 'Audio Volume' in my kubuntu (19.10), and it doesn't look like there is a way to add it to that menu. However, I've added Kmix and it does work for volume Up/Down and Mute/Unmute, but does not work for the Mic On/Off. Previously I could easily control that with my laptop button.

Comment: perhaps you've made changes to or removed packages  such as `pulseaudio`? you may want to reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio` or `sudo apt purge pulseaudio` + `sudo apt install pulseaudio`

Comment: I certainly did not delete pulseaudio. I've reinstalled it and here's what I see. https://i.imgur.com/D5GwM96.png Which is not what we want.

Comment: thanks for uploading a screenshot of your screen.  From this, it shows that you have `Kmix` installed.  This is a sound channel mixer and volume control package.  When installed, it takes the place of pulseaudio for channel mixing and volume control.  You should be able to set global shortcuts for your volume control under the Kmix component.  Alternatively, you can completely uninstall Kmix with the command `sudo apt purge kmix`.  After rebooting, the "Audio Volume" category should come back up.  If this is the solution, please reply and tag me @nmath so I can post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the software center
- Type *pulseaudio control panel* in search filed and search
- Install it